# How to make OptionButton in Userform autoselect based on the date and time

Tags: userform, radio-button

I have a created a Userform that auto-populates the Date and Time into a TextBox (TextBox2).

What I want is for the OptionButtons (OptionButton 5 = Start Shift) (OptionButton6 = End Shift) to auto select based on the date and time from TextBox2. I am only focused on the time, the date isn't as important.

I want OptionButton5 to autoselect if the time is equal to or before 10AM.

I want OptionButton6 to autoselect if the time is equal to or after 10:01AM.

I wasn't sure if this was possible. Ive been looking for any code I could find, and haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the code below will help you achieve what you are wanting, this will enter the date and time into Textbox1 when the Userform is Initialized, then under the Textbox1_Change method, it will check whether it is before or after 10:00 and set the option buttons accordingly:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim val As Variant
val = Format(TextBox1.Value, "hh:mm")
If val > "10:00" Then
    OptionButton1.Value = True
Else
    OptionButton2.Value = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    TextBox1.Value = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
End Sub
```